# auto generate 12 months

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do i auto generate the table to 12 months like this:

```
  tbl_name    
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
  10
  11
  12
```

Here is what i have done:

`tbl_month` from `tableA` will display `1`

```
SELECT tbl_month FROM tableA WHERE type='Settings' and code='M'
```

Comment: Please tag data base engine name.

Comment: Do u want generate numbers  from 1 to  12 or that?

Comment: yes, generate 1 to 12 using the select statement from tableA and tableB

Comment: You say 1 and 3 are pulled from tableA and tableB respectively, but if all you want is a list of 1-12, why does that matter?

Comment: What do you have inside Table A and B? Can you post some sample data?

Comment: sorry mistake; month from tableA is 1 and i would like auto generate it to 12 

*less writing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to generate numbers from 1 to 12 then try this :

```
;WITH tableA
     AS (SELECT 1 [MM]
         UNION ALL
         SELECT [MM] + 1
         FROM   tableA
         WHERE  [MM] < 12)
SELECT *
FROM   tableA
```

Additionally, you can UNION/JOIN this with any other table.
In many cases, for example, you want select a row which is missing in `tableB` (in a sequence):

```
;WITH tableA
     AS (SELECT 1 [MM]
         UNION ALL
         SELECT [MM] + 1
         FROM   tableA
         WHERE  [MM] < 12)
SELECT *
FROM   tableA
       LEFT JOIN tableB
              ON tableA.MM = tableB.MM
```

This will show you rows for those months too which are not in `tableB`.

Comment: this is a generalized way of generating numbers. Check @Giorgi's answer too.

Answer (score 3):

If your mission is just to generate months then you can do this as simply as:

```
 select m
 from (values(1),(2),...(12)) t(m)
```

If you want to left join then:

```
 select *
 from (values(1),(2),...(12)) t(m)
 left join TableA a on t.m = a.m
```